# parse transaction logs to get NFT Transfer information

Tags: web3js

Is there any easy way to parse transaction logs in order to get information about:
who sent the token
who received the token
what token has been transferred
what was the price for that

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use web3 getPastEvents filtering the Transfer event.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents